# findOneAndUpdate with sort and limit

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
var query = Session
   .find({ player: player, logout: null })
   .sort({ 'login.date': -1 })
   .limit(1);

query.exec(function(err, data) {
  var session = new Session(data);
  session.logout = logoutEvent;
  session.save();
});
```

How can I convert this into [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)?

Here is an example of using findOneAndUpdate but im not sure how to add `sort` and `limit`:

```
var query = {'username':req.user.username};
req.newData.username = req.user.username;
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, req.newData, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
    if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
    return res.send("succesfully saved");
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add sort to you options dict:

```
{ upsert: true, sort: { 'login.date': -1 } }
```

Comment: What about a limit?

Comment: ah. find`One`AndUpdate. so the limit is implied

Comment: @ZachSmith haha we all have that one braindead moment :P